# jquery find and length

Tags: javascript, jquery

js length doesnt show correct length of element and find() cant get value of an elements
 i have code like this:

```
<div id="mobiles">
    <input name="mobiles[]" id="mobiles0">
    <input name="mobiles[]" id="mobiles1">
    <input name="mobiles[]" id="mobiles2">
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

inputs with id mobiles1 and more are dynamically created by appending elements.
i want to get number of inputs i used 2 way

1. `$('#mobiles').children('input').length;` // it return nothing
2. `document.getElementsByName('mobiles[]').length;` // it returns incorrect value for example 8 for 3 input or 16 for 4 input or 32 for 5 input elements. it seems like powers of 2

second problem is i cant get value of third input and after that. i just get value of first and second input with below code.

```
var xlen = document.getElementsByName('mobiles[]').length;
for (i = 0; i < xlen; i++) {
    var data = $('div').find('#mobiles' + i).val();
    alert(data);
}
```

or using `$('#mobiles'+i).val();` return nothing.

Comment: " are dynamically created by appending elements" Are you somehow trying to access the elements before they are created?

Comment: no .when the  elements are created i push a button to get data

Comment: So after it loads how do you read the new fields? I think your issue is there.

Comment: u can see this example i wrote.https://jsfiddle.net/hsoft/q4vufw0b/6/

Comment: And your jsfiddle is working fine. ln is the length and seeing in increase with each click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$("#mobiles input").length` should also work, check next example:

```js
function getValues()
{
    var xlen = $("#mobiles input").length;

    for (i = 0; i < xlen; i++)
    {
        var data = $("#mobiles #mobiles" + i).val();
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mobiles">
  <input name="mobiles[]" id="mobiles0">
  <input name="mobiles[]" id="mobiles1">
  <input name="mobiles[]" id="mobiles2">
</div>

<button onclick="getValues()">Get Values</button>
```

Comment: thans. it work for static element but length doesnt work correctly for dynamic element. check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hsoft/q4vufw0b/6/

Comment: it is confusing me. i dont realize why it happens

Comment: @hsoft Use the inspector tool in these cases: Your problem is at this line:    `$('.'+field).append('<input type="'+type+'" placeholder="" name="'+field+'[]" class="form-control dataCheck '+field+' '+field+ln+'" data-type="'+field+'" id="'+field+ln+'">');`. Basically the first time you create a new input with class `<field>` (or `mobile` in this particular case). Then, the second element you create will be appended to the all elements with class `mobile`, the main div plus the previous created one and so on...

Comment: @hsoft Here you have one possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/pxt2wc7q/. Basically I change the class of the main div to be unique.

Comment: thanks your solution worked. it seems changing the class name of main div solved the problem. but i dont understand why it conflict with id cause im counting the length of specific id childeren. anyway thanks again

Comment: @hsoft like commented above, the `append` was adding multiple nested inputs each time you execute it. Because, every new item you append has the class `.mobile` and the append is targeting all elements with class `.mobile`. Also, if this answer helped you consider to up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not recommended to combine vanilla js with jQuery.

to loop through inputs use pure jQuery.

```
$("#mobiles input").each(function(){
      console.log($(this).val());
});
```

edited to remove size recommendation

Comment: You should not being using `size()` since the method has deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. So the OP should be using `.length` which is the proper way.

Comment: This is what I was going to post. If you are committing to jQuery you might as well go the full way with it, at least as far as DOM interactions go.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the length:

```
$("#mobiles").find("input").length
```

Getting value of third element in the array

```
$("#mobiles").find("input")[2].value
```

There are others ways of course, but this works for sure.

Comment: $("#mobiles").find("input").length doesnt work but $("#mobiles").find("input")[i].value worked fine. thanks

Comment: if the second worked then the first one should have worked as well, otherwise the $("#mobiles").find("input")[i] wouldn't work, check if you have a typo any where, or post your exact code